# How to calculate LTE handover delay in NS-3

Tags: ns-3, handoff

Hello stackoverflow community,

I am trying to calculate handover delay for a LTE simulation using LENA module in NS-3. To do so, I am using Simulator::Now().GetSeconds() function to log current simulation time at the beginning and the end of handover process.

Surprisingly the results I get from several handovers (distance between Ue and eNB nodes differ but Ue speed is the same for all) all indicate the same handover delay, as if it is constant. Also the calculated delay is too small to be true. Some results:

12.12 Prepare Handover (start)
12.12 Handover Recv Ack
12.1242 Handover Done To 8 (end)

^^(4.2ms)

19.8 Prepare Handover (start)
19.8 Handover Recv Ack
19.8042 Handover Done To 6 (end)

^^(4.2ms)

Am I calculating it wrong? 
Or is it because of miss-configuration of my scenario? If so would you mind providing me with some configuration which have effect on handover delay? I already have tried adding noise and x2linkdelay but no luck there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright guys, I figured that it's because of the RRC Configuration which was ideal instead of real. Although results are not as good as I expected, they make sense now :P